# Get the context of an Activity in a Serializable class

Tags: android

I have a class that implements 'Serializable' but i am unable to get the context of my main activity in it. Here is my code for this class:

```
public class Game implements Serializable{
private String name;
private ColorTheme theme;
private int distance = 0;
private int score = 0;
boolean boom = false;
protected Context context;

public Game(MainActivity context){
this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
}
```

I want to close my game inside this condition but it is not giving me any option to finish the context. Please help me where i am wrong. I think the context is not successfully implemented in this Serializable class. Help needed

Comment: You cannot finish a `Context`. You can only call `finish()` on an `Activity`. Note that by calling `getApplicationContext()` you're getting a reference to the `Application` class which is not your activity instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a simple way to exit the app. Try it like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("Exit me", true);
((Activity)context).startActivity(intent);
((Activity)context).finish();
```

Here MainActivity is depends on your project requirement. You can change it as per your need.